# Calculate a normal average from uniform samples

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, mean

Ok, this feels like it should be pretty basic, but maybe I'm missing the right terminology to google this.

Suppose I have a (non-analytical) function $f(x)$ that I have evaluated for a large number of uniform values $x_i \in [-1, 1]$. That is, I have uniform samples of points $(x_i, f_i=f(x_i))$.

Now I want to know what the expectation value $\bar{f}$ of $f$ would be if the values of $x$ were drawn from a Normal distribution of width $\sigma \ll 1$. Ultimately, I want to do this for different values of $\sigma$, so that I can generate a plot of $\bar{f}(\sigma)$.

My first intuition was to simply multiply the values $f_i$ with a weight $w_i$ where $w_i$ is the value of the probability density function (PDF) for the normal distribution with $\sigma$. I would then normalize with $\sum w_i$ and average the weighted and normalized $f_i$. However, that does not seem to produce correct results.

I've also tried [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) (taking a simple average of the $f_i$, but randomly excluding $f_i$ if a random value $r_i \in [0, 1] $ is smaller than the normalized PDF at $x_i$). This gives me good results, but it's quite slow.

Is there a better method than rejection sampling for this? It still seems to me like I should be able to average my original $f_i$ with some appropriate weighting, but maybe I'm wrong.

There's lots of methods for generating normal-distributed $x_i$ from uniform $x_i$, of course, but that's not what I want to do: I don't want to evaluate $f(x)$ for any *new* values $x_i$, so all I have are the existing $f_i$. My $x_i$ in this case are in fact random, but in principle it should also work for $x_i$ on a dense regular grid.

Comment: So you want $E\{f(X)\}$, where $X$ is normally distributed?  It is just a simple integral, $\int f(x)g(x) dx$, where $g(x)$ is your normal density.  What am I missing?

Comment: In the continuous limit, that equation looks right to me, but what do I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

On principle you simply cannot estimate$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \varphi_\sigma(x)\,\text dx$$based on $f(x_i)$'s with $x_i\in(-1,1)$ since there is not information for $f(x)$ when $x\not\in(-1,1)$...

Now, if $\sigma$ is small enough for$$\int_{-1}^{1} \varphi_\sigma(x)\,\text dx\approx 1$$you can consider$$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\varphi_\sigma(x_i)$$as a pseudo-importance sampler but, depending on the function $f$, the approximation can completely go south, i.e. be completely unreliable: take an extreme example when $f$ is very large on $(-2,-1)$ and very small or null over $(-1,1)$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/\varphi_\sigma(x) &\text{when }x\in(-2,-1)\\
0 &\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \varphi_\sigma(x)\,\text dx= 1$$
while
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\varphi_\sigma(x_i)=0$$

Obviously, if the support of $f$ is $(-1,1)$ then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \varphi_\sigma(x)\,\text dx= \int_{-1}^{1} 2f(x) \varphi_\sigma(x)\,\frac{\text dx}{2}=2\mathbb E[f(U)\varphi_\sigma(U)]$$when $U\sim\mathcal U(-1,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand there could be a pathological $f(x)$. In this particular case, $f(x)$ can be considered 0 outside $[-1, 1]$ and also $\sigma$ is going to be sufficiently small so that $\int_{-1}^{1} \phi(x) dx \approx 0$. Just to make sure: $\phi_\sigma(x)$ the PDF for normal distribution, right? Then your answer would correspond to my initial intuition, except for the normalization with $\sum\phi_\sigma(x_i)$. Let me try that...

Comment: If $f(x)\equiv 1$, the average $\bar{f}$ should be 1 as well (independent of $\sigma$), which doesn't seem to be what I'm getting with $\frac{1}{n} \sum f_i \phi(x_i)$ (or with $\frac{2}{n} \sum f_i \phi(x_i)$ )

Comment: Actually, I think it turns out that my original intuition was correct after all: $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i \phi_\sigma(x_i)\right) / \sum_{i=1}^{n} \phi_\sigma(x_i)$ does seem to work! What was tripping me up was a complication that I left out of the description here: I actually have another "category" parameter in my data, and I want to do do the averaging for each category indpendently. If I do the averaging before a `groupby` for the  category, I also have to divide by the number of categories. Or, do the `groupby` first.

Comment: @xian If you agree with / double check the result and edit your response accordingly, I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: No, my answer is correct, this is a standard importance sampling approximation. If you disagree please write another answer.

Comment: Fair enough.. I'll look into it more. In any case, thanks for the technical term, "importance sampling approximation", which is something I can look up ;-)